# sendmail function not working

Tags: php, sendmail

i just wanted to try mail function in php which i have used earlier.i formatted my system so i had to re install xampp and my send mail code is not working

```
<?php
    if(mail("mymail@gmail.com","hi","hii")) {
        echo 'sent';
    } else {
        echo 'fail';
    }
?>
```

I did all the changes to php.ini and sendmail.ini

**sendmail.ini**

```
[sendmail]
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465
smtp_ssl=ssl
default_domain=localhost
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username= mymail@gmail.com
auth_password= mypwd
pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=
force_sender= mymail@gmail.com
hostname=localhost
```

**php.ini**

```
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 465
sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost
sendmail_path = "\"E:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

I changed everything but still its not working.

Comment: did you restart the apache after changing php ini?

Comment: When you say not working - what is the error in your log files? Or are you assuming by non-receipt the config is not working?

Comment: just use phpmailer class to send mail